# Error using an if statement with the -AND conditional and 2 variables

Tags: powershell, if-statement

In my current script, I have defined 2 variables at the top of the script:

```
$errorcode = 0
$time_errorcode = 0
```

The rest of the script consists of 2 foreach loops for each one of these variables.  Basically if the loop succeeds, then the variable stays at 0 and if the loop fails, the variable changes to 1.  I am trying to figure out now how I can properly "exit" the script with the exit code that I need based on whether or not these forloops succeeded or failed.  The way I am doing is as follows:

```
if ($errorcode = 1 -and time_errorcode = 1){exit 0"}
if ($errorcode = 1 -and $time_errorcode = 0){exit 1"}
if ($errorcode = 0 -and $time_errorcode = 1){exit 2"}
```

The problem that I'm running in to is that PowerShell is telling me that this snippet: `if ($errorcode = 0 -and $time_errorcode = 1)` is invalid.  The error that I'm getting is:

> The input to an assignment operator must be  an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.

I guess I don't know how to properly compare these 2 variables together to get the exit code that I desire.  What is the best procedure to do this?

Comment: Use `-eq` instead of `=`. `if (($errorcode -eq 1) -and ($time_errorcode -eq 1))`

Comment: As @lit said, use the -eq operator instead of =.

In PowerShell, the equal sign is an assignment operator while the -eq is used strictly for equality. You're re-assigning your variables to those values in your statement.